# Collapsible panel + button issue

Tags: html, css

I have a collapsible panel, and I wish to change the image (from + to -). I found a few solutions online, and the one I wish to implement is through css. However, for some, reason, something is wrong with my css. Can someone tell me what exactly?

HTML

```
       <div class="panel panel-default at-panel">
          <div class="panel-heading at-panel-heading">Panel<img class="collapsed at-collapse-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panelBodyNA"/></div>
          <div id="panelBodyNA" class="panel-body at-panel-body collapse">
            <p> Test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
img.at-collapse-button.collapsed:before{
    content:url("../img/plus.png");
}

img.at-collapse-button:before{
    content:url("../img/minus.png");
}
```

Comment: :before and :after  does not work with img

Comment: @Dmitriy I deleted my comment not realizing you were talking about the selector here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use :before pseudo element with an image element.
You have to follow this approach:

```
<div class="panel panel-default at-panel">
  <div class="panel-heading at-panel-heading collapsed at-collapse-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panelBodyNA">Panel</div>
  <div id="panelBodyNA" class="panel-body at-panel-body collapse">
    <p> Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You css then:

```
.at-collapse-button.collapsed:before{
    content:url("../img/plus.png");
}

.at-collapse-button:before{
    content:url("../img/minus.png");
}
```

Or any other css you would like to have because content url will not bring you an image.

But you can manipulate your pseudo element as you would like ex:

```
.at-collapse-button.collapsed:before{
   position: relative;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-image:url("../img/plus.png");
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use span.